# The result is the definition Increasing Function

Tags: functions

Increasing Function :

$$\forall x_1,x_2 \in D_f : x_2>x_1  \Rightarrow f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)$$

Strictly Increasing Function :

$$\forall x_1,x_2 \in D_f : x_2>x_1  \Rightarrow f(x_2)> f(x_1)$$

---

Can we conclude that if $f$ be  Increasing Function then : $$f(x_2) >  f(x_1)\Rightarrow x_2>x_1$$

---

And also

Can we conclude that if $f$ be Increasing Function then : $$f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)\Rightarrow x_2>x_1$$

Answer (score 0):

For your first case, no, because $f(x_1) = f(x_1)$ yet $x_1 > x_1$ is false.

For your second case, yes.  Suppose $f$ is increasing and $f(x_2) > f(x_1)$.  Suppose to the contrary that $x_2 > x_1$ is wrong, so that $x_2 \leq x_1$.  Then $f(x_2) \leq f(x_1)$, a contradiction.

Comment: i'm sorry .I edited

Answer (score 0):

Take the contrapositive of the definitions, which are logically equivalent.

For the strictly increasing case, $x_2 > x_1 \implies f(x_2) > f(x_1)$, is equivalent to the contrapositive statement,
\begin{align} \neg(f(x_2) > f(x_1)) &\implies \neg(x_2 > x_1) \\
f(x_2) \leq f(x_1) &\implies x_2 \leq x_1, \text{ relabel }x_2 \leftrightarrow x_1 \\
f(x_2) \geq f(x_1) &\implies x_2 \geq x_1
\end{align}

Similarly for the other definition.